# How to have a tiny highlighted icon on my button in a web page to show new updates are present?

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp, servlets

I have currently made a Java web application. It has a server(MyServer) and the client side(the webpage). The client makes request to MyServer to get some information. MyServer now makes request to Confluence API server to get information from our latest Confluence page in our Confluence space.

When we click on "What's New" button (in our client -website) - the latest page in our Confluence space shows in the What's New web widget. The user can click on the What's New button and the most latest page from the Confluence page shows up.

What I would like to do now is-

1. Every time a new update is made, (either changes in the same Confluence page/or new Confluence page is created), a little highlighted icon shows on my "What's New" button. (Please find the sample required picture attached - also, like in any chat applications {Whats app, FbMessanger etc when a new message is received}).
2. Once my particular user sees that new update that tiny highlighted icon goes away for that particular user.
3. The tiny highlighted icon should show for all the logged-in users for the first time if they have not opened the new update yet. If user1 opens it - the tiny highlighted icon should go away for that user1 (and the "What's New" button should become a normal non-higlighted button) But, this tiny highlighted icon should stay for user2 if they have not opened it.
4. Then if we make a new change in our Confluence page and user1 has not seen this new update yet - the tiny highlighted icon should show again for user1.

How should I go about it? Thank you for your help.
[image]

Comment: Well, you probably have a "version" for your updates and thus need to track what version a user saw. If you want to keep experience consistent you'd need to store which version the user looked at last on the server side (a cookie might work but only within the same browser) and you display the button if the current server version is newer than the one last seen by the user (you could show all changes between those 2 versions then if you have that info). To check for new versions you could use web socket/push messages or periodically poll the server.

Answer (score 1):

About the generic solution to your problems,

1. You need to implement websockets to get the realtime chat like notification from back-end
2. You can write a JavaScript code to target an element, in this case your notification icon.
   Consider the it's ID is #notifIcon

   **to hide**

   ```
   document.getElementbyId('notifIcon').style.display = 'none'
   ```

   **to show**

   ```
   document.getElementbyId('notifIcon').style.display = 'block'
   ```
3. To keep it user specific, you can take data from database schema and update accordingly
4. Again update your data with websockets